# Paypal system configure in Fusion Ticket

Tags: paypal, ticker, ticket-system

How to configure the Paypal System in Fusion ticket.
Remain to systems are working in My Fusion ticket.

1. Payment: Cash Shipment: Point of sale (It is wokring)
2. Payment: Invoice: Please pay within 10 days or within 3 days of Event if sooner Shipment: Email(It working)
3. PayPal (Unable to see the Option) in the POS user.
   [image]

Configured into the paypal in FUsion TIcket from admin user.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting Google turned up [Payment and Shipment Options](http://www.fusionticket.org/index.php/help/start/doku.php/id,payment/), which looks like a complete walkthrough.

Comment: I have create paypal account without card details valid email address.Select the Paypal it goin to paypal gate way.But I got a error We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com

Comment: Okie it resolved I have one more question it support only paypal or other payment methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160449/fusion-ticket-support-only-paypal